# put a mask on a C string

Tags: c, string, mask

I have a C string which has a value x.x.x where x can be 1 to 9. what's a good algorithm to make it x.x.8 for example the last digit fixed at 8.

I am thinking of using strtok function.

Comment: What do you mean a mask? If you have fixed length string you can string[4] = '8' ;). Please clarify. You can also use regex.h to find exact match position and nmatch for match count.

Answer (score 0):

use this function:

```
void mask_string(char s[]) {

    int j = 0,i;

    while (s[j] != '\0')
        j++;

    i = j-1;

    s[i] = '8';  
}
```

this works even if you don't have a fixed length string

Comment: It won't you have a mistake in your code it will cause segfault.

Comment: thanq soo much @Maquefel . i forgot to check that. I've edited my answer

Comment: You are welcome =) pChar = &s[0];
   while (*(++pChar + 1) != '\0');
   *pChar = '8';